# forEach mehod token ,invalid TypeElidedFormalParameter

Tags: java

I have a method `getListOfTags()` that returns a `Set<String>`. I have a method `getListOfClasses()` that also returns a `Set<String>`.

I tried to combine them in one by using the forEach method:

```
scraper.getListOfTags(globalDocument).forEach(tag -> tagsAndClasses.add(tag));
scraper.getListOfClasses(globalDocument).forEach(class -> tagsAndClasses.add(class));
```

[image]

On the second forEach, the class variable name gets underlined and I get this error:

> Syntax error on token "class", invalid TypeElidedFormalParameter

When I change the variable name to e.g. `classes` the problem goes away. Why is it that I can't name my variable `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in Java. You cannot use it as a variable name.

Here is a list of other keywords, and a deeper dive into their rules.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

And here is a more up-to-date list -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

**EDIT** - In situations like this, I like to use `eachClass`, or something like that.